# Compiled Groovy Scripts

Tags: java, groovy

As I understand, there exists at least 2 ways to compile a Groovy script in Java.

1. use javax.script.ScriptEngine to convert to a [CompiledScript](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/CompiledScript.html).

   ```
   ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("Groovy");

   Bindings bindings = new SimpleBindings();
   bindings.put("foo", 1234);

   Compilable compEngine = (Compilable)engine;
   CompiledScript cs = compEngine.compile("if (foo == 1234) true else false");
   cs.eval(bindings);
   ```
2. Use `GroovyClassLoader#parse`, do some intermediate work, and then call `GroovyObject#invokeMethod(String, Object[])`.

Note - the following code is from [Groovy in Action](http://www.manning.com/koenig2). I found it to be a great book for learning Groovy.

```
GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader();
// Note, assume that the Groovy script gets compiled to a class that 
// includes a method, "do". And "do" accepts an `Integer` argument, "foo."
Class foo             = gcl.parseClass("if (foo == 1234) true else false");
GroovyObject hello    = (GroovyObject) foo.newInstance();
Object[] args         = { Integer.valueOf(1234) };
assert                  true == (foo.invokeMethod("do", args));
```

As I understand the differences between these 2 approaches, the first one involves populating a `Bindings` map with `key-value` pairs - variable name to value. Then, we execute the `CompiledScript` via `CompiledScript#eval(Bindings)`, where the `Bindings` argument gets mutated.

However, let's say that I wanted to pass a `Foo` class object into the method, `Foo#do`. And, rather than evaluating `if (foo == 1234) ...`, I needed to, in source code, write:

`if(fooObj.getFoo() == 1234) ...`.

Then, as a result, I find that I would need to **post-process** the DSL to include the correct way to get at `foo`.

In general, is there a simpler way to achieve the second approach per my above example?

Answer (score 3):

There are actually more than 2 options. All of them are described in the docs (see http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.3.8/html/documentation/#_integrating_groovy_in_a_java_application), but in any case, I wouldn't recommand using JSR-223 (javax.script) because it is a very poor integration mechanism.

Using for example a `GroovyShell` or a `GroovyClassLoader`, you can set your own base script class which would let you set your `foo` instance very easily, but you could also call any method from your base script class.

BTW, the method that all Groovy scripts will implement is not `do` but `run`. So imagine you have the following base class:

```java
public abstract class MyDSL extends groovy.lang.Script {
    Object fooObj
    public void setFooObj(Object foo) { fooObj = foo; }
    public Object getFooObj() { return fooObj; }
}
```

and a holder class for `Foo` like this:

```java
public class FooHolder {
    def getFoo() { return 1234; }
}
```

then you can create a script this way:

```groovy
CompilerConfiguration config = new CompilerConfiguration();
config.setScriptBaseClass("test.MyDSL");
GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader(),config);
Class<? extends MyDSL> scriptClass = gcl.parseClass("return (fooObj.getFoo()==1234)");
MyDSL v1 = scriptClass.newInstance();
v1.setFooObj(new FooHolder());
Object result = v1.run();
```

Note that this is really one way to do this, but not necessarily the best one given your needs. Maybe you could describe a bit more what you want to achieve but Groovy has a lot of options, from compiling scripts like this, to compiling classes which extend your own classes or interfaces. Take a look at the docs and let us know.

Comment: Basically I'm calling a Groovy script from Java. What I like about `CompiledScript` is that I can re-use it rather easily.

With the `Class` approach, I need to modify the actual Groovy DSL Script to be a legal class. However, with the `CompiledScript` approach, I can simply keep the Groovy DSL as-is. Then, I can evaluate it by calling `CompiledScript#eval(Bindings)`.

Comment: The `Script` class already contains a `Binding` instance so nothing would prevent you from doing this too. Just be aware that if you don't create a new instance, you are not thread safe.

Comment: `if you don't create a new instance, you are not thread safe` - of the `Bindings`?

Comment: Yes, you share the same binding instance.

Comment: to add to this... CompiledScript is also only a wrapper for groovy's Script class.